# Sending survey with apex

Tags: apex, survey

Im trying to send surveys Apex, as indicated in the documentation, we must pass a `String` and a `ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailInput`, but passing these parameters gives me the following error:

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sendSurveyInvitationEmail(String, ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailInput) from the type Survey.`

I've also tried not to pick up what it returns but it doesn't work this way either. The survey settings are activated in my org. What am I missing?

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_Survey_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_Surveys_sendSurveyInvitationEmail_1

Code:

```
        String surveyId = [SELECT Id FROM Survey WHERE DeveloperName = 'survey_test' LIMIT 1][0].Id;
        ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailOutput surveyOutput = new ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailOutput();
        ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailInput surveyInput = new ConnectApi.SurveyInvitationEmailInput();
        surveyOutput = Survey.sendSurveyInvitationEmail(surveyId, surveyInput);
```

Comment: hi Mariia! I tried to fill some of them but I still get the same error, even some of the required ones like isPersonal​Invitation, I get this error when I try to inform it: 'Variable does not exist: isPersonal​Invitation'

Comment: May you please also check the API version of your class? Should be 50 or higher. (never mind, it doesn't work in developer console either)

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought at first, but its the API version 55 :( thx a lot for your help anyways! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ApexType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_Survey_static_methods.htm?q=survey) is `Surveys`, not `Survey` in the `ConnectApi` namespace. `Survey` is in namespace `Schema` and represents the SObject.

```
surveyOutput = ConnectApi.Surveys.sendSurveyInvitationEmail(surveyId, surveyInput);
```

Comment: I also tried that and its not working for me, I get this error: 'Variable does not exist: Surveys' but if I write 'Survey' it seems ok, am I missing to add something additionally? thx a lot for your help :) looks like there is also an ApexType for Survey, im very confused right now: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Survey_static_methods.htm

Comment: updated my answer to include namespace

Comment: Wow, amazing! For real, the docs are misleading.

Comment: @Gatosaurio I understood the difference, your documentation is set to v50, if you change it to v56, it will automatically change Survey on Surveys

Comment: I filed a doc feedback form -- as you can see, this caused me some grief as well to get to work

Comment: Sorry for answering late, this finally worked for me!! thanks a lot to both of you cropedy and Mariia for your help!!  I have also filled in the feedback form :)